# Compile SASS/SCSS on the server

Tags: css, sass

I have an application that has a page where the user can choose two colors, color-primary and color-secondary, and press a button to apply the colors.

Once the button is pressed I want this page to update the values of SASS/SCSS variables and compile a new style sheet.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you be specific about "on the server". What language, OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use inline styles on the html, as this will override any css files. You could store the values in a cookie so that you can retrieve them later on. When you check for the cookie and find it you can set it again, that way it shouldn't expire. It should be fine for storing styles. You could use https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ to store and retrieve the cookies.

If it this was for some sort of backend cms and you need the CSS files to be stored permanently you could always just write the changes straight to a custom CSS file and link to that, this would be better than compiling SASS/SCSS on a server. I would use `fwrite()` in PHP for something like that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

If you really need to compile on your server though, first you'll need to install SASS/SCSS on to your server and then you could run it from `exec()` in PHP, or something similar in another language in the same way that you would from the command line.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts but I really need a way to run SASS/SCSS on the server. You got it right about having a CMS and I have a bunch of SASS/SCSS variables that control changes on many different components. You are right about having SASS/SCSS on to my server and having a way to run it and that's exactly what I'm trying to learn from others experiences.

Comment: You will need a way in PHP (if that is what you are using), to accept and handle all the variables that you want to change. Then you will need to create a settings.scss file using `fwrite()`, which is imported at the top of you output file. Then run SCSS with the `exec()` function.

Comment: I think that I'd prefer to create the CSS files without using SASS, it's the same principle, you would just need to be clever with the classes that you write to keep them to a minimum. Then I'd `fwrite()` a new custom.css file and link that in the head after the main styling.

Comment: Another thought, do you have control over what will be installed on all the servers that this CMS will be used on? If not then it's highly unlikely SASS will be installed on any of them.